# Allow users to pick Green Jenkins builds to deploy

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, devops

I want to allow testers/BAT users/Ops etc to have a list of builds to pick from that they can deploy to a list of environments. The list should only contain builds that have passed all the way through our automated Jenkins Pipeline and the environment list will be a pre defined list. They should be able to pick from old and new builds. The deployment job is all setup. I was looking at writing a simple web page interface that hooks into Jenkins via the JSON API but if there is any way of doing this via Jenkins then that would be great.

Comment: I think the easiest is to parse the following json: 
http://{Jenkins_Master}:8080/job/{JOB_NAME}/api/json?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds[number,result,building,url]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. CI build store successful artifacts in artifact repository (i.e: Artifactory)
2. Build has a parameter called "BuildToDeploy" or similar. That build parameter is created with [Dynamic Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in) so it gets populated with list of builds from Artifactory.
3. Testers choose a build from a list of green artifacts.

In order to achieve step 2 as "Default value Script" of parameter you add some Groovy code that gets the artifact list from artifact repository. In Artifactory it would be something like **jfrog rt list CIBuildArtifacts**

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough with Jenkins declarative pipeline you can do that in a very simple OOTB way. Although you have to twist the idea a bit.

In general for any pipeline that you would like to be able to promote you could have an extra stage using [input](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input), submitter

> An optional comma-separated list of users or external group names who are allowed to submit this input. Defaults to allowing any user.

and [parameters](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters).

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            input {
                message "Should we continue?"
                ok "Yes, we should."
                submitter "alice,bob"
                parameters {
                    choice(name: 'DEPLOYMENT_ENV', choices: ['one', 'two', 'three'], description: 'where to deploy?')
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, ${PERSON}, nice to meet you."
            }
        }
    }
}
```